# what protocol does terminal shell login use?

Tags: ssh

SSH or Secure Shell is a cryptographic network protocol for operating network services securely over an unsecured network. Typical applications include remote command-line, login, and remote command execution, but any network service can be secured with SSH.(from wiki)

Answer (score 0):

It uses the *secure shell* protocol, which is documented in RFCs 4251 through 4254:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4251
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254